# meaning of "not for today only"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, ambiguity

I heard, "The store will be having a sale, not for today only"

What does "not for today only" mean in this sentence? Does the "only" modify "not for today" or does the "only" modify "today"?

Comment: I don't think that the person who said this was a native English-speaker. It is pointless trying to analyse bad English. (Note how the future tense of the main clause clashes with the idea that there is a sale today.)

Comment: Unless this is a correction, it is, as Greybeard says, unidiomatic. "The store will be having a sale, and it will not just be for one day, Friday" is idiomatic, even with 'just' before 'be' rather than 'one'.

Comment: "Standard" wording would be *The store will be [is?] having a sale, **[for] today only***. So although in and of itself the cited usage isn't actually idiomatic (hence @Greybeard's comment), you just *might* encounter it from a native speaker using slightly quirky phrasing to draw attention to the fact that this particular sale ***isn't*** the normal "for today only" kind (maybe it lasts all week, I dunno). But in any event, ***only*** can only modify ***today***, regardless of whether the standard construction is being [slightly facetiously] negated or not.

Answer (score 1):

Because "for today, only" is a common expression in regard to sales, I would think it applies to the whole expression.

However, it's not the usual way of expressing it.  Normally, a sale that last a week or a month would give the time, or omit it entirely.  (The reason for giving "today only" is to make people think they better grab while it's available.)